# Restrict insertion of new row if a row exists with certain field values

Tags: postgresql, constraint

Using a Postgres DB. I have a table let say `t` with columns `txn_type, txn_id`. I want to add a constraint where it restricts to insert new row if I have a row with particular values existing in table.

e. g row 1

`withdrawal, txn1`

I am trying to add a constraint where it restricts to insert new row with `txn_type` <> 'withdrawal' and `txn_id = txn1`.

e.g it restricts to insert row with following values

`non_withdrawal, txn1`

My situation is like if a record exist with `transaction_type` = withdrawal & `txnid=txn1` then no non-withdrawal record with same txn id should be able to be inserted.

Comment: @ArshadMunir You tell that "restricts to insert new row with txn_type <> withdrawal and txn_id = txn1." Does this means: if a row with some txn_type and txn_id is inserted then another row with the same txn_type and txn_id is allowed but the row with another txn_type but the same txn_id is restricted?

Comment: Is the situation symmetric, so that if a non-withdrawal already exists, you can't also add a withdrawal?  Or is it path-dependent?

Comment: @Akina correct.

Comment: @jjanes my situation is like if a record exist with transaction_type=withdrawal & txnid=txn1 then no non-withdrawal record with same txn id should be able to be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Create user-defined function which checks needed condition. Use it in CHECK constraint:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t ( txn_type VARCHAR(255),
>                  txn_id VARCHAR(255)
>                );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION my_check (text, text)
> RETURNS BOOLEAN
> AS $$
> SELECT NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
>                     FROM t
>                     WHERE t.txn_id = $2 AND t.txn_type != $1 );
> $$ 
> LANGUAGE SQL;
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE t 
>    ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (my_check(txn_type, txn_id));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('asd', 'qwe');
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('asd', 'qwe');
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('zxc', 'qwe');
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "t" violates check constraint "my_constraint"
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (zxc, qwe).
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t;
> ```
>
> ```
> txn_type | txn_id
> :------- | :-----
> asd      | qwe   
> asd      | qwe
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=668f4fd32c20f565be8f8b8e9f0e8a4e)*

Answer (score 0):

Answer left in a comment by [matigo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/228577/matigo):

Two ways to do this would be through a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger or via a stored procedure. With a trigger, you can be sure that every application that writes directly to the database must follow the prescribed rules. With a stored procedure you can (potentially) simplify the entire process if there are multiple steps that must be followed in succession.